# PHP blank and special characters error of filenames

Tags: php, image, utf-8, special-characters, filenames

```
<div id="gallery">

<?php  

$directory = 'people';

$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_parts=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;


foreach (glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file){
    if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $file_parts = explode('.',$file);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
    $title = basename($file);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    echo '
    <div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url(thumbs/'.$file.') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
    <a href="'.$file.'" title="whatever you want : '.$title.'" rel="pan1" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
    </div>';
    $i++;
}



?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

This is my code sample for a dynamic image gallery. I shows all images in a directory automatically with thumbnails from another folder. Here is my problem: If I use a blank char or a special characters in file name then it doesn't show the file at all. I want to use blanks and special characters such as (ç, ö, ş) because I want to use image title as a description of the image without having to write any extra text. Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Sample : http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/galeriler/kopya.php

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my answer because I don't have the time to fix it. Anyhow: encode your HTML output and quote your background URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit I don't know all characters which are and aren't valid in filenames on different operating systems and filesystems, but I do know that some can be problematic, and that it depends on the platform. My personal recommendation is to just avoid the whole issue.

Either store the file meta data(in your case, the title) in a database and then associate each title to some serial numbered file like `159.jpg`, or consider encoding the filename down to a small subset of ascii, as yielded by [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode)()

eg, store `ç.jpg` urlencoded as `%C3%A7.jpg` and then just urlDecode() for display...

beware of hitting the maximum file name, and possibly file path lengths. They too vary per platform. This is another point for using a database, as it avoids long filenames.

Comment: Yeah, it seems risky trying to use text that's essentially unfiltered for filenames. It would be encoded, but not filtered. Sounds like a security risk or bug waiting to happen. Serial numbers are cleaner and safer.

Comment: I'm just too bad wit the databases now. I need to study on that.

Comment: Beware of `base64_encode` as one of its chars (`/`) is invalid in all the major OSes.

Comment: @AlixAxel, oh... wow, I never knew / was part of base64's alphabet. Edited.